# Cómo cargar datos desde PostgresSQL a un Gráfico Highcharts?

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql, symfony2, highcharts

He estado investigando primeramente como visualizar un gráfico `Highchart` en mi proyecto en `Symfony 2.8`. Ahora resulta que quiero poder cargar los datos desde mi base de datos en `PostreSQL`. He visto que existen varias formas y la que creo más me conviene es a través de un `JSON` pero no tengo idea de como pasarle los datos al gráfico.

Aquí dejo el código de mi gráfico:

```
    $(function () { 
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Comportamiendo de las Ganancias en el Año'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['E', 'F', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'J', 'J', 'A', 'S', 'O', 'N', 'D']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Ganancias'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Indicador 1',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'Indicador 2',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

Lo que necesito es que los datos los cargue desde algún lugar en mi proyecto donde hago la consulta y los obtengo para así sustituir Indicador 1 e Indicador 2.

Answer (score 0):

Falta un poco de contexto para ver qué tienes del lado de backend, pero imaginando el contexto, creo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$arreglo= [
    'Indicador1' => [1,0,4],
    'Indicador2' => [5,7,3]
];

$this->render('Bundle:Carpeta:vista.html.twig',array(
    'arreglo' => json_encode($arreglo);
));
```

Luego con Javascript haces un parseado:

```
var data = JSON.parse({{arreglo}});
```

Con ésto ya deberías de poder colocar lo que necesitas en la función:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Indicador 1',
    data: data.Indicador1
},
```

Sería una opción.